# Am I overlooking anything in this "voting" implementation using ASP.NET MVC/C#/SQL?

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net-mvc

**Requirement:** to have a thumbs up/thumbs down "vote" on a given page. It should track who voted, when, and what their choice was. This will be used to show a total vote count, possibly a chart to show votes over time.

**SQL Table**

- PageId BigInt FK PK
- UserId BigInt FK PK
- Vote TinyInt
- DateVoted DateTime

PageId and UserId are, together, the PK for the table. Possible values for the "Vote" field are 1 and -1. The DateVoted field will be set to DateTime.UtcNow on vote.

Are there fields I'm missing that you would consider important?

On-page implementation will be vaguely similar to YouTube's.

Comment: I don't know about missing fields (these seem adequate), but if this is going to be a real app, you should make sure that a user can only vote once, and that you make it hard to fake votes for other users, and hard to create fake accounts.  Nothing you've said here precludes that, though.

Comment: Thanks Merlyn. About the vote once comment, by making the PageId and the UserId the PK of the record, that will force unique, aka 1 vote. Now, for false user accounts... hmmm... in my case, the app uses Facebook accounts, so I suppose that will be difficult.

Comment: If you're using another system's authentication, then you probably won't have to worry about that as much.  Facebook might use a captcha on account creation, for example.  You can't really do anything against someone determined enough (someone hiring people to farm out captchas), but it is good to give a little thought to the likely-hood and potential risk :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would say the right answer depends on your requirements. As long as this is all the information you need and your foreign keys work with the related tables, then it seems fine to me.

Note that `tinyint` is not signed so -1 is not an option. So I'd use `bit` instead (0 = downvote, 1 = upvote).

Comment: Using `bit`, he'd have to make sure that he supports deleting records, either via a true delete, or a `deleted` flag.  That way a user can undo their vote if they accidentally clicked.

Comment: Right. I assumed he'd want to do that anyway.

Comment: @Jonathan: If he's doing work for an existing project, and they use soft-delete flags, he might not know to include it.  Just figured it was worth mentioning :)  Oh, also +1 for `bit`.

Comment: Great comments, I didn't think of that scenario (user accidentally voting, or wishing to un-vote). Thanks for the `bit` tip.

Comment: Are there any fields you'd consider important? I believe what I laid out would support the app scenario, but maybe there's something I'm missing (from lack of experience developing this sort of feature)?

Comment: @Chad: The main thrust of my comment is that the fields should meet your requirements. That's not really something anyone else can help you with. I recommend you spend some time thinking about how it should work and what functionality you will want. For starters, I would *definitely* allow users to undo a vote either way. Once we have your requirements, then we could address the question of if any more columns are needed. As presented, I don't see anything that is necessarily missing.

Comment: Great, that's what I was hoping to hear. Essentially, I've got it covered so long as no new requirements are brought up. I asked only because there could be something that was a "lesson learned" by someone, only once they got deep into developing it. Thanks!